# Index check behavior

Tags: jquery

I have a really strange problem with this code:
In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USvwp/) it alert's that "red" has index of 0 (which I want to alert), but on my local computer it alert's that check is not working...
Can someone tell me why is this happening?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
  <meta name="author" content="Dejan Peic"/>
  <meta name="description" content=""/>
  <meta name="keywords" content=""/>



 <style type="text/css">
 .wrapper{
 width:100px;
 height:150px;
 border:1px solid #000000;
 margin:0auto;
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 }
 .red{
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 display:block;
 background-color:red;
 }
 .blue{
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 display:block;
 background-color:blue;
 }
.green{
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 display:block;
 background-color:green;
 }
.checkIndex{
width:150px;
height:20px;
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var red = $('.red');
  var active = $('.active');
  var redIndex = red.index();
  var activeIndex = active.index();
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.wrapper div:last').addClass('active');

  $('.checkIndex').click(function(){

  if(redIndex > activeIndex){
  alert('Red has index 0');
  }

  else{
  alert('check doesnt work :(');
  }

  });

  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  </div><!--/wrapper-->
  <div class="checkIndex">Check index of RED</div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Have a look at the left side bar of the fiddle. It says `onLoad` which means that your code is executed when the pages was loaded. It's always good to understand the tools you are using ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move these lines:

```
var red = $('.red');
var active = $('.active');
var redIndex = red.index();
var activeIndex = active.index();
```

inside of your `$(document).ready(...)` function.

Outside of that function the specified DOM elements don't exist yet.

It only works on jsfiddle because by default that site automatically wraps your code in an `onload` handler, which achieves the same effect.

Comment: +1 In fact, there is a guarantee that they don't exist yet, since the script is above the elements.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. indeed - I hadn't at that point cottoned onto it being jsfiddle fixing the script, instead of an unusual browser.